# How do I obtain the system theme's color palette?

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt4, pyside

For matplotlib purposes I require the default color a system uses for window backdrops. In Ubuntu, for exmaple, it's a very light grey, somewhat lighter than window XP's.

I am changing the color of the default matplotlib patches to this grey to make them look native. However, I don't want to hardcode it. Is there any way to obtain the native background color from within PyQt?

Answer (score 2):

Qt defines a bunch of system colours in `QPalette`. To obtain a certain colour in PySide, call

```
QColor(QPalette().color(state, role))
```

where `state` represents the state of the colour (i.e. `QPalette.Disabled`, `QPalette.Active`, `QPalette.Inactive`, `QPalette.Normal`) and `role` represents the symbolic colour to be determined. A full list of colour roles can be found at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum.

The colour role you are probably looking for is `QPalette.Window`, defined as "A general background color."